# Remaining work reports in Agile

Tags: tfs

I'm a new to Agile.I'm pullzed to how to determine the remaining work times, is it determined by the contributors or by the managers, or calculated through the check_in auto?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your question. Are you wondering how the time remaining is calculated, or who should maintain it?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how the time reamainning is calculated and who should maintain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remaining work is just a field that you need to update manually. There is no auto calculation done for you. 
Normally the one that owns the task is updating the remaining work field. A lot of teams do a daily standup and update the remaining work of everybody in that daily standup.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this comes from the Remaining Effort field in the Task Work Items (assuming you're using the MSF Agile Process Template).

Comment: Yes, I adopt the MSF Agile Process Template.